# Guzzle 6: Get URL that was "resolved" from base_uri

Tags: guzzle6

In [Guzzle 3](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/client.html#creating-a-client) you can get the resolved URL (without actually opening it) like this:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://foo.com',
]);

$request = $client->get('bar.html');

echo $request->getUrl();
```

In [Guzzle 6](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html) this is not working anymore. Is there another way to get "`http://foo.com/bar.html`"?

Comment: Note that `$client->get()` returns a response object in version 6. To get the effective URL look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35443523/57091).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history middleware, works as advertised:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

$container = [];

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(Middleware::history($container));

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://foo.com',
    'handler' => $stack,
]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'bar.html');

/* @var RequestInterface $request */
$request = $container[0]['request'];

echo $request->getUri();
```

For reference, see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html#history-middleware.

Comment: The correct command to retrieve the RequestInterface instance is:

    `$request = $container[0]['request'];`

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but for the reference.

You can do it with `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\UriResolver::resolve($baseUri, $relUri);`

It converts the relative URI into a new URI that is resolved against the base URI.

`$baseUri` and `$relUri` are instances of `\Psr\Http\Message\UriInterfaceUriInterface`.