# URI from Response on GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I need to get the `URI` from the `Response` of `GuzzleHTTP`, currently using the `getAsync`, and processing the at least 50 items at the same time and needed a way to get the `URI` that I use from the guzzle `Client`.

```php
$groups->each(function($group) {
    $promises = $group->map( function($lead, $index) {
        $client = new Client(['http_errors' => false]);
        return $client->getAsync($lead->website, [
            'timeout' => 5, // Response timeout
            'connect_timeout' => 5, // Connection timeout
        ]); 
    })->toArray();
    settle($promises)->then( function($results) {
        $collections = collect($results);
        $fulfilled = $collections->where('state', 'fulfilled')->all();
    })->wait();
});
```

it seems like the `Request` has this `getUri` method but the `Response` doesn't and can't find in the interface or class and in the documentation., hope someone can help

Edit: tried `getEffectiveUrl` but this only works on Guzzle 5, currently using 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is for guzzle 5**

On the response you dont have a getUri method cause only the request has this.

If there is a redirect or something happening you may use the following method the get the response url

```
$response = GuzzleHttp\get('http://httpbin.org/get');
echo $response->getEffectiveUrl();
// http://httpbin.org/get

$response = GuzzleHttp\get('http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http://www.google.com');
echo $response->getEffectiveUrl();
// http://www.google.com
```

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/http-messages.html#effective-url

**Guzzle 6**

Guzzle 6.1 solution right from the [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\TransferStats;

$client = new Client;

$client->get('http://some.site.com', [
    'query'   => ['get' => 'params'],
    'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) use (&$url) {
        $url = $stats->getEffectiveUri();
    }
])->getBody()->getContents();

echo $url; // http://some.site.com?get=params
```

Credits to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35443523/8193279

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering., please see edited line.. currently using Guzzle 6

Comment: This is helpful for Guzzle 5.*